# number of rows in section

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

I have a table view which populates from a plist. in a plist I have a Categories array:

```
Catgeories - Array
  item 0 - Maths
  item 1 - English
  ....
```

in the same plist i have a Notes array

```
 Notes - Array
  item 0 - Dictionary
     Title - My maths note 1
     Text - This is algebra 
     Category - Maths
  item 1 - Dictionary
     Title - My English
     Text - This is algebra 
     Category - English
```

in number of sections i have...

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
// Return the number of sections.
return [self.categories count];
 }
```

In numberOfRowsInSection before i added the categories array to the plist i could simply use

```
  return self.notes.count;
```

which produces a duplicate in every category: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xScH.png

but now in this method i should expect to return the number of rows based on the section, not sure how to do this

Comment: I think the problem is your Notes array is array of array. How do you know how many arrays are for Math Vs English in it? If you setup your example just as shown your number of sections are 2 and number or rows in section is 1.

Comment: Your Notes array is 1-dimensional containing items for all Categories.  Instead, make it an array of arrays where each subarray is an array of dictionaries (first subarray for Category 0 only, second subarray for Category 1 only, etc).  _Then_ you can do self.notes[section].count, etc because then self.notes[section] will be an array of items only for the specified category/section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like that:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    return self.notes.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.notes[section].count;
}
```

You get array of you notes base on the section and return count of the array.

//EXTENDED
If you want to have as many section as data in Category array use:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
    {
        return self.catgeories.count;
    }
```

The self.note array contain dictionaries object with Category key and I believe you want to show all of the data for section where category is equal section category. To do that you have to filter your notes array, try this (I assume that you have distinct objects in Caregory plist):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Get category
    NSString *cat = self.catgeories[section];
    //Filter notes array
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category =[cd] %@", cat];
    NSArray * catArray = [self.notes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    return catArray.count;
}
```

Comment: +1 for legibility. I also prefer using literal syntax while populating tables.

Answer (score 2):

I have edited the answer.
If you wanna access large amount of data, i suggest that you store your data in core data instead of plist, 
For getting number of rows for each section you can use this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // check if the count of the array is greater than number of sections
    if (self.notes.count > section)     
        return [[[self.notes objectAtIndex:section]allObjects]count];
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i get the same problem as the previous answer - undeclared identifier on indexPath

Comment: You your plist file is in the same format as shown above this code should work. Maybe your code in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is wrong. See edited post.

Comment: I dont know what im doing wrong.The plist seems fine. In the number of sections method i return the count of the number of categories in the category array. ie. Maths and English returns 2 sections. then ive tries the methods  above for the number of rows in section method and nothing works

Comment: I have edited my answer. In case you didnt notice, here is the code again                                                               - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.notes objectAtIndex:section]allObjects]count];
}

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error -  [__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]:index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

Comment: since your array has only 1 object, your app is crashing. You can put a check like if (self.notes.count > section) before the return statement in numberOfRowsInSection Method.

Comment: Hey, this update gives an control may reach end of non-void function. Which is fair enough because there can be a condition where the return statement is not even reached

Comment: put return 0 after if loop to remove that warning

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if you want to return different number of rows in each section:-

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView 
   *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
   (NSInteger)section
 { 
 int rows=0;
  if(section==0)
   {
    rows=1;
    }

   if(section==1)
  {
   rows=2;
  }
rerurn rows;
  }
```

Comment: That's hard coding. The dude perhaps has hundreds of rows / section (for all we know). Not a smart way to do it

Comment: @sam, agree but this is just an example here op does not have 100 rows. So according to question it contains two arrays